# Why is the mesh deformed when sculpted with Subsurf modifier?

Tags: objects, sculpting

I am creating a pillow for my couch.

But when I click on my base, it just deforms it like this:

[image: Screenshot of deformation]

Does somebody know how to fix it?

After ticking dyntopo it looks like that... 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8685/what-is-the-difference-between-a-subdivision-surface-modifier-and-multiresolution. Use Multires modifier instead.

Comment: Or you can tick Dyntopo in the left toolbar.

Comment: Doesnt help much ((

Comment: I solved the problem by clicking apply subsurf modifier )

Comment: I wonder how that didn't help much.. Your cube was probably default one, and geometry was being added only by Subsurf. Sculpting mode needs geometry to allow details. Sculpt does not work with Subsurf so while sculpting mesh with Subsrf it treats the mesh as the one without any modifiers and hence (in your case) without any geometry. By applying Subsurf you created geometry necessary for Sculpt - but that's quite bad practice as there won't be any flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use a subsurf modifier. If you apply it, it will be incredibly slow or far too low poly. For sculpting, use the multi-res modifier like this:

[image]

Otherwise, dyntopo is very easy to use (although the resulting topology is less than desirable). Here is a sculpting example with dyntopo:

[image]