# Why can't I sculpt on a plane when using Subdivision Surface?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, subdivision-surface, multiresolution, zbrush

When I add Subdivision Surface I just simply can't sculpt anymore, but...it works with multiresolution...any ideas why is that?

Thanks

Comment: To sculpt you need more vertices, a plane with no subdivisions will not work. Try subdividing the plane. As an alternative enable [**Dyntopo**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html?highlight=dyntopo) so that you create new vertices as you sculpt.

Comment: Subsurf isn't designed to work with sculpting.. subdivisions added with it are accessible for sculpting only once it's applied. Multires is the one which is designed for that, allowing to edit subdivided surface with sculpt brushes. There doesn't seem to be any real reason to sculpt with Subsurf.

Comment: @MrZak Thanks, this was helpful! Can you add you're comment as an answer? so I can mark this post as solved. Thank you again!

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8685/what-is-the-difference-between-a-subdivision-surface-modifier-and-multiresolution

Answer (score 1):

[Subdivision Surface modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html) (or Subsurf) isn't designed to work with sculpting. Subdivisions added with it are accessible for sculpting only once the modifieir's applied. [Multiresolution](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/multiresolution.html) is the one which is designed for that, allowing to edit subdivided surface with sculpt brushes. There doesn't seem to be any real reason to sculpt with Subsurf.